# Using google-maps-react npm packing-- is there a way to click on the map to add a marker?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-react

I am using the google-maps-react component and I cannot seem to find any information about how to dynamically add a marker by clicking on the map. https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react

I can add a marker just fine with code, but I want the user to be able to add it by clicking, and don't see how to add that event listener. I already have an event listener for displaying marker info.

Is it not an available feature? Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

My code:

```
export class MapContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showingInfoWindow: false,
      activeMarker: {},
      selectedPlace: {}
    };

    // binding this to event-handler functions
    this.onMarkerClick = this.onMarkerClick.bind(this);
    this.onMapClicked = this.onMapClicked.bind(this);
  }

  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });
  };

  onMapClicked = props => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map google={this.props.google} onClick={this.onMapClicked} style={{width: '70%', height: '80%', position: 'relative'}} className={'map'} zoom={2}>
          <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick} name={"Current location"} />

          <Marker
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          title={'The marker`s title will appear as a tooltip.'}
          name={'SOMA'}
          position={{lat: 37.778519, lng: -122.405640}} />

          <InfoWindow
            marker={this.state.activeMarker}
            visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          >
            <div>
              <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        </Map>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drop a marker by clicking on the map by using the following code.

```
mapClicked = (a, b, c) => {
if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
  this.setState({
    showingInfoWindow: false,
    activeMarker: null
  });
} else {
  let lat = c.latLng.lat();
  let lng = c.latLng.lng();
  let houseLocation = { lat: lat, lng: lng };
  this.setState({ houseLocation });
}
```

mapClicked takes in three arguments the third 'c' is the coordinates on the map. So you can just take those coordinates and make a marker at those locations. This code only lets you drop one marker, and each time you click the map the 'houseLocation' just changes. But you could just change the code to make a new Marker instead.